# Crystal Reports: Special Fields translation

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports and have it installed in English however I am developing reports for a German speaking company. Special fields like the number of pages (Page x of y) are appeared in English naturally. Is there a way to have CR translate these fields without changing the language of the program, so I could still work in my English environment but the rest of the people could get the reports in German? 
Thank you.

Comment: you can do it by changing the regional setting of the desktop and then restart the computer then open the crystal report... http://scn.sap.com/thread/1345134

Comment: That didn't work.. besides I want to be able to work on my computer using English at all times.. but thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can create a text object with the words Page of (in German of course)
Then drop the special field called Page number directly in the text box after Page and the special field called Total Page Count after of

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of that!